# Collections: Array, Vector and ArrayList. Differences and appropriate usage

Tags: java, arrays, vector, arraylist

First I should say that in my book (2005), `Vector<E>` is (extensively used) in place of arrays. At the same time there is no explanation with differences between the two. Checking the [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for `Vector` class it's pretty easy to understand its usage.

Doing some additional research on StackOverflow and Google, I found that the `Vector` class is actually deprecated and to use `ArrayList` instead, **is this correct?** [I also found an extensive explanation about differences between Array and ArrayList.](http://java67.blogspot.it/2012/12/difference-between-array-vs-arraylist-java.html)

The part that I can't really understand: **Is there a rule on where I should use `ArrayList` instead of simple arrays?** It seems like I should always use `ArrayList`. It looks more efficient and should be easier to implement collections of values/objects, is there any down side with this approach?

Comment: `Vector` vs `ArrayList`: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197). Arrays vs `List` backed by `ArrayList`: it will depend on your design, but I would prefer `List` for being dynamic and already handle all the operations (add, remove, get) instead of rewriting them, also you can use `Array#asList` to move an array to `List` and `List#toArray` for vice versa.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Array`, except `java.lang.reflect.Array` which is a utility class for array manipulations. Do not mix this and `ArrayList` which is an implementation of the `List` interface.

Comment: @fge when OP refers to *Array* it means a simple array of primitives or objects like `int[]` or `Object[]`.

Comment: Yep, sorry i totally mixed up. Just meant simple arrays as metioned by Luiggi. Such as String[], int[], etc..

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, I have kind of figured this out -- I just wanted to clear the confusion, because there actually _is_ `Array` in the JDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some history:

- `Vector` exists since Java 1.0;
- the `List` interface exists since Java 1.2, and so does `ArrayList`;
- `Vector` has been retrofitted to implement the `List` interface at that same time;
- Java 5, introducing generics, has been introduced in 2004 ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_programming_language#History)).

Your course, dating back 2005, should have had knowledge of `ArrayList` at the very list (sorry, least), and should have introduced generics too.

As to `Array`, there is `java.lang.reflect.Array`, which helps with reflections over arrays (ie, `int[]`, etc).

Basically:

- `Vector` synchronizes all operations, which is a waste in 90+% of cases;
- if you want *concurrent collections*, Java 5 has introduced `ConcurrentHashMap`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` etc, you should use those;
- DO NOT use `Vector` anymore in any event; some code in the JDK still uses it, but it is for backwards compatibility reasons. In new code, there are better alternatives, as mentioned in the previous point;
- since Java 1.2, `Vector` does not offer the same thread safety guarantees as it used to offer anyway.

The latter point is interesting. Prior to `Iterator` there was `Enumeration`, and `Enumeration` did not offer the possibility to remove elements; `Iterator`, however, does.

So, let us take two threads `t1` and `t2`, a `Vector`, and those two threads having an `Iterator` over that vector. Thread `t1` does:

```
while (it.hasNext())
    it.next();
```

Thread `t2` does:

```
// remember: different iterator
if (!it.hasNext())
    it.remove();
```

With some unlucky timing, you have:

```
t1                  t2
------              ------
hasNext(): true
                    .hasNext(): false
                    removes last element
.next() --> BOOM
```

Therefore, `Vector` is in fact *not* thread safe. And it is even less thread safe since Java 5's introduction of the "foreach loop", which creates a "hidden" iterator.

Answer (score 3):

The basic difference between an `array` and an `ArrayList` is that an array has fixed size, whereas, `ArrayList` can dynamically grow in size as needed. So, if you are assured that your array size won't change, then you can use it. But if you want to add elements later then a an `ArrayList` which is an implementation of `List` interface, is the way to go.

Although an `ArrayList` is internally backed by an `array` only. So, internally it also uses a fixed size array, with an initial capacity of *10* (which can change for that matter), but that detail is internally hidden. So, you don't have to bother about the changing size of the `ArrayList`.

Whenever you add elements more than the current size of array in your `ArrayList`, the internal array is extended. That means, the regular expansion of size can become an overhead, if you are regular inserting a large number of elements. Although this is rarely the case. Still, you can also give your own initial size while creating an `ArrayList`. So, that's upto you to decide.

As for `Vector` vs `ArrayList` discussion, yes `Vector` is now deprecated (not technically though, but it's use is discouraged as stated in comments by @Luiggi), and you should use an `ArrayList`. The difference is that `Vector` synchronizes each operation, which is nearly never required. When you need synchronization, you can always create a synchronized list using `Collections.synchronizedList`.

For more on this discussion, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).

An `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List`. There are other variations too. Like you also have a `LinkedList`, to get the functionality of a traditional *linked list*.

Comment: *`Vector` is now deprecated* it is not technically deprecated, but its usage is highly discouraged, similar to scriptlets for JSPs.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Yeah, should have added that. Thanks :)

Comment: @Downvoter Please leave a comment. Anything wrong with the post?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Well, I guess that is not related to this question though. I just mentioned about `LinkedList`, so that OP can look over the options.

Comment: In fact, `Vector` also implements `List`, so by programming to interfaces, you can easily replace `List<Object> theList = new Vector<Object>();' by `List<Object> theList = new ArrayList<Object>();'.

Answer (score 0):

> > Vector Class is actually deprecated and to use ArrayList instead, is this correct?

Yes this is correct. Vector class and some other collections are deprecated and replaced with new collections like ArrayList, Map, etc. Here are [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) reasons why Vector is deprecated

> > Is there a rule on where i should use ArrayList instead of simple Arrays?

Almost always. I can think of two reasons why you should use arrays:

- Makes JNI calls easier. It is MUCH easier to send a simple array from C++ to Java than an object of ArrayList
- You can gain a little bit of performance, since access to elements of simple array does not requires boundaries checks and method calls.

On other hand using ArrayList gives a lot of advantages. You do not need to think about controlling array's size when you add new element, you can use simple API of ArrayList for adding/removing elements from your collection, etc.

Comment: Why is `Vector` deprecated? Your link discusses the differences and states that both have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @nif Sorry, my fault. Updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add my two cents.

If you need a collection of primitive data and optimization matters, arrays will *always* be faster, as it eliminates the requirement of auto-boxing and auto-unboxing.